# selecting elements at different levels

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, windows-7

Previously we had a table with column names at the div level, as so:

```html
<TABLE id = 'someTablsID'>
  <TR>
    <TH>
      <DIV>&NBSP</DIV>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <DIV>Last Name</DIV>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <DIV>First Name</DIV>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <DIV>Age</DIV>
    </TH>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

We would have an element (the table) and do a 
findBy with xpath = th[div[text()]] to get each heading (yes some were blank).  We had to find them in order as that is the order of the values underneath.  Now, the developers we have no control over decided to put some with span and some not, as in

```html
<TABLE id = 'someTablsID'>
  <TR>
    <TH>
      <DIV>&NBSP</DIV>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <DIV>
        <SPAN>Last Name</SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <DIV>
        <SPAN>First Name</SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <DIV>
        <SPAN>Age</SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </TH>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

so my findBy will not work any more.  I tried several new xpaths including
**th[div[text()] OR div[span[text()]]]** and 
**th[div[text()] | div[span[text()]]]** but neither worked.  I read something about not(self:) somewhere but did not understand it.

What would be a good way to express the xpath I need?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is deeper path. You did not combine `th` with `span`, like this:

```
th[div[span[text()]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
th[div[.//text()[normalize-space()]]]
```

The above XPath would match `th` that contains `div` element where the `div` contains non-empty text node (doesn't matter the text node is inside `span` or any other element or directly inside the `div`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with CSS selectors, you can use the code below to print the text.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#someTablsID > tr > th > div"));
for (WebElement element : elements)
{
    System.out.println(element.getText().trim());
}
```

I find CSS selectors easier to use myself... YMMV.

The CSS selector `#someTablsID > TR > TH > DIV` is read: find an element with an ID (#) `someTablsID` that has a child (>) `TR` that has a child (>) `TH` that has a child (>) `DIV`. From there you can grab the text and you will get it whether or not it's actually in the child `SPAN`.

[CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)